# Program to insert input text around selected text

Tags: gratis, windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

I am looking for a Windows 7 program that allows me to press a shortcut, get asked to input a character and have the currently selected text surrounded with what I entered.

I need:

- it to be free
- it to run on Windows 7
- it to be triggered with a configurable shortcut
- it to ask me what I want the text to be surrounded with

eg. I select `sample text`, press a shortcut, enter `"` into an input box and the text now is `"sample text"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can easly be done with [AutoHotkey](http://ahkscript.org/).

AutoHotkey (AHK) is a free, open-source macro-creation and automation software for Windows that allows users to automate repetitive tasks. It is driven by a scripting language that was initially aimed at providing keyboard shortcuts, otherwise known as hotkeys, that over time evolved into a full-fledged scripting language.

Here is a script:

```
#i::

    clipsaved:= ClipboardAll

    Send, ^c
    WinGetTitle, CurrentWinTitle

    InputBox, inputVar, Input character, Input character wich will surround the text.
    clip := Clipboard
    clip = %inputVar%%clip%%inputVar%

    Clipboard := clip

    WinActivate, %CurrentWinTitle%
    Send, ^v

    Clipboard := clipsaved

return
```

Keep in mind that script works through manipulating clipboard. It tries to restore it but anyway be aware that it can change clipboard.

Comment: Could you give me a starter script if possible? I really don't understand AHK script that much to create what seems like a complex script!

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Which hotkeys should launch script?

Comment: I'll be able to change the shortcut keys - but if you can, say something like Win+I?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ I edited my answer and added the script.

Comment: Great! +1. I'll try it out ASAP :)